# Slim Framework authentication

Tags: php, slim

I searched for a good time on Google for a Authentication lib for Slim framework but all that came up was single user based authentication with `BasicHttpAuth`. What are my alternatives here apart from implementing my own auth.

Apart from hashing passwords, I'm not very good with sessions well I know how to work with them but keeping sessions secure is another thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm currently writing a [library to handle that now](https://github.com/jeremykendall/slim-auth), but it's in early alpha not yet ready for use.  In the meantime, you can refer to this project as an example: https://github.com/jeremykendall/flaming-archer.

Pay special attention to the [login route](https://github.com/jeremykendall/flaming-archer/blob/develop/public/index.php#L244), the Auth [DbAdapter](https://github.com/jeremykendall/flaming-archer/blob/develop/src/FA/Authentication/Adapter/DbAdapter.php), and the [Auth middleware](https://github.com/jeremykendall/flaming-archer/blob/develop/src/FA/Middleware/Authentication.php).

It uses an [array of URIs](https://github.com/jeremykendall/flaming-archer/blob/develop/config/global.php#L82) to secure certain routes, in this case just the admin group of routes.